# parsing files with mapreduce in hadoop

Tags: java, parsing, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a log file named 2014-11-10.log, the structure is like this

`head1, body1_a
head2, body2
head3, body3
head1, body1_b
...`

The body with same header may not be equal, for example, body1_a and body1_b are not equal.

I want to parse each body into csv files, where each csv file is corresponding to a head.

for example,

`head1, age:5,money:1000,sex:boy
head2, email,something@gmail.com, age,20, sex,boy
head2, email,something@yahoo.com, age,20
head1, age:5,money:1000`

all the lines with head1 can be parsed into a csv file:

`age,money,sex
5, 1000, boy
5,1000,null`

Suppose I have 3 head in each log, then I will parse them into 3 csv files.

I try to write a mapreduce program for parsing such a big data sets.

My mapreduce program takes one log file to a mapper, the parsing logic is done in the mapper, and use the mapper to write the csv files. In my program, no reducers are needed.

For example, when encountering head1 of processed line, mapper write to head1.csv after parsing its body. The key is head and the value is the parsed body( For example, "5, 1000, boy" is the value)

However, the program is too slow than I expected (one hour about ten thousands of logs, each log is not exceeded 1MB) . Even though I use an empty mapper ( I remove the parsing logic and just write constant string to the csv file), it still run about one hour.

Why is such design of program is too slow and How can I improve that.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you share the `Mapper` codes ?